# Can I force a path to walk?

Tags: into-the-breach

Is the path to walk to get to a tile always automatic, or am I able to override where it would have me walk to? In the screenshot below, I'd like to have my artillery move to the marked square, but it would be great if he would walk around the landmine instead of through it. Is there a way to force mechs to walk a certain path?

[image: Landmines are bad]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no way to force a unit to walk a certain path, but it's not necessary to do so anyway. Landmines, A.C.I.D., lava, and other tile hazards are only triggered when stopping on that specific tile, not when pathing through it.